# flutter session version failed

Tags: flutter, android-studio, session, dependencies, version

This happens when i try to use the flutter_session 0.1.1, being stuck on this issue for 3 hours

Because shared_preferences_linux >=0.0.4-nullsafety <2.0.0 depends on shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety and shared_preferences_linux <0.0.2+1 depends on path_provider ^1.6.11, shared_preferences_linux <0.0.2+1 or >=0.0.4-nullsafety <2.0.0-∞ requires shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety or path_provider ^1.6.11.
And because path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1, shared_preferences_linux <0.0.2+1 or >=0.0.4-nullsafety <2.0.0-∞ requires shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety or path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
And because shared_preferences_linux >=0.0.2+1 <0.0.4-nullsafety depends on path_provider_linux ^0.0.1 which depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1, shared_preferences_linux <2.0.0 requires shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety or path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
And because shared_preferences >=0.5.8 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on shared_preferences_linux ^0.0.2 and shared_preferences >=0.5.4+8 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on shared_preferences_platform_interface ^1.0.0, shared_preferences >=0.5.8 <2.0.0-nullsafety requires path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
And because every version of flutter_session depends on shared_preferences ^0.5.8 and path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, every version of flutter_session requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
And because file_picker 5.2.2 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.1.2 and no versions of file_picker match >5.2.2 <6.0.0, flutter_session is incompatible with file_picker ^5.2.2.
So, because fyp depends on both file_picker ^5.2.2 and flutter_session ^0.1.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fyp depends on both file_picker ^5.2.2 and flutter_session ^0.1.1, version solving failed.)

i don't understand this error and find a lot of sources on the internet but all of them are not related to this error

Comment: They gave you a poem of error, hope someone can help you

Comment: it caused your package is not support for current flutter version.  you can see this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_session/score
 the package is not support `null-safety`.

Comment: its not recomended to use it, but if its mandatory, you may try to run your app without `null-safety`  ::: > `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.